# Div not showing scrollbars with jScrollPane

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

Apologies if this question has already been asked, but I'm struggling to find an answer on SO.

I'm using jQuery jScrollPane on a `div`. I can tell the plugin has been linked correctly as the standard browser scroll bar is removed, but no jScrollPane scrollbar is added in replacement, I just can't scroll down the content..

My markup is as simple as:

```
<div class="classa">
  ...Long content here...
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".classa").jScrollPane();
});
```

Has anyone experienced this before? Is there something simple I'm missing?

I think I might be missing some CSS somewhere or something, otherwise I don't know how to specify the colour of the scrollbar anyway...

Your help would be much appreciated

Comment: `try{$(".classa").jScrollPane();}catch(e){ console.log(e); /* or alert(e) */}` and tell us what that shows?, this will test if `jScrollPane`  can be called, other wise throw an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some sample CSS code for the jScrollPane example at this URL: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/basic.html.

The sample CSS can be found at: 
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/styles/jScrollPane.css

Hope that helps.

---

My mistake - that CSS is to be used with an older version of jScrollPane. The correct CSS to use can be found here: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css

Comment: Ah I'll give that a try, I was looking at the old css

Answer (score 1):

try enclosing the ".... long content here....." in the

tag.

like so:

```
<div class="classa">
<p>
...Long content here...
</p>
</div>
```